# Bat Script folder remove brackets - i.e parentheses

Tags: windows, batch-file

Howdy I have this script which was made for me

```
@echo off
rem Eliminate all folders present at the same level of the Batch file
rem and move their contents one level up
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /AD') do (
   cd "%%a"
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /AD') do (
      move "%%b" ..
   )
   move *.* ..
   cd ..
   rd "%%a"
)
```

It removes the folders and empty the files in the folder to where this script is ran.

It works fine but one problem. If the folder has brackets "()" in the name it will not work. Can this be changed to allow the use of the brackets

Cheers

Comment: For American readers, 'brackets' in this context would refer to parentheses, I assume. `(` and `)` rather than `[`, `]`, `<`, or `>`.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Your code works fine with a directory called `(folder)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /ad /b') do if exist "%%~A" (
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ('dir /b "%%~A"') do move "%%~fB" .\
    rd "%%~A"
)
```